# Why is the local devel server not working with Yesod?

Tags: windows, haskell, windows-8, yesod

I'm running the latest version of Yesod and the Haskell Platform on Windows 8.

I made a new scaffold project with yesod init and then executed the following commands within the project directory:

```
cabal install
yesod devel
```

Yesod devel responds

```
Devel application launched: http://localhost:3000
```

However, when I go to localhost:3000 with Chrome, it gives the following error:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

This is different from a random localhost port (which just gives the following):

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:3010
```

Any ideas why this is the case and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I ran into the same problem tonight on windows 7. Hoping someone can help us both.

Comment: Tried disabling windows firewall, no change in behavior.

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine on me right now, but have you tried using different browsers?  Perhaps something is going wrong with the way Chrome communicates with the devel server.

Comment: Wasn't the firewall or browser, and I've had issues with OS X & Ubuntu as well. Anyone else have luck? Would love to try Yesod since a web framework in Haskell is intriguing, but the experience trying to get it initially setup is frustrating & doesn't leave much confidence in the rest of the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug was introduced to Warp which caused issues on Windows, and was fixed about a week ago. The newest version of the yesod-platform should resolve the issue (it worked correctly in Windows for my test).